# jQuery: selectionStart returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection-api

## Situation

**browser**

Google Chtome 69

**html**

```
<textarea id="message" name="message">
    // input some messsage
</textarea>
```

**js(jQuery)**

```
$(function () {
  $("#message").on("keydown keyup keypress change", function () {
      //this part runs correctly
  })

  $('#message').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if ((e.wich && e.wich === 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode === 13)) {
      var $textarea = $(this);
      var sentence = $textarea.val();
      var position = $textarea.selectionStart;
      var length = sentence.length;
      var before = sentence.substr(0, position);
      var after  = sentence.substr(position, length);
      sentence = before + "\n" + after;
    }
  });
});
```

When I input something in the #message textarea and push Enter key in the area, nothing would happen. According to Chrome developer tool, selectionStart method seems to return `Undefined`.

## Needs

Enter key has been made disabled in this form page in order to avoid submitting the data mitakenly.

**js**

```
function fnCancelEnter()
{
  if (gCssUA.indexOf("WIN") != -1 && gCssUA.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

However, in this textarea, I want to enable user to add a break line by pressing Enter key.

I'm sorry but I don't have much knowledge about jQuery and javascript. Please tell me how to do.

Comment: `selectionStart` is a property of a standard JS element, *not* a jQuery element. Try `$textarea[0].selectionStart` instead. Also, `wich` should be `which`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you for your answer. By making `$selectionStart` `$selectionStart[0]`, this property returns a proper value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace `$textarea.selectionStart` by `$textarea.get(0).selectionStart`. Then try again.